# Свободный деплой веб-сервиса .NET (ограничения лицензии Apache 2.0 на ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net, лицензирование

Как уже многие знают, последние версии .NET Framework выходят под свободной лицензией MIT. Однако, например, подразделение ASP.NET MVC идёт с лицензией Apache 2.0.

Хотелось бы узнать, какие есть общие требования к разработчику .NET перед релизом? Могу ли я разместить *некоммерческий* (без возможности его распространять/продавать) веб-сервис так, чтобы не отчитываться перед Microsoft, ничего не регистрировать и не иметь *проблем с копирайтами*? Ведь, по идее, он будет работать только для меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы, советую читать лицензии. Они в большинстве своём написаны на человеческом языке (с очевидными исключениями вроде вирусного семейства *GPL).

Лицензия Apache 2.0 — это пермиссивная опенсорсная лицензия, она предполагает свободное использование для любых целей, хоть коммерческих, хоть нет. Вы можете делать с кодом что угодно, вплоть до переписывания кода и изменения лицензии, но в этом случае уже имеющийся код остаётся под старой лицензией, а в изменённых файлах нужно указывать, что файл был изменён.

Если вы собираетесь только использовать библиотеку, то единственное требование — указать хоть где-нибудь в своей работе содержимое файла NOTICE. Файл NOTICE можно дополнять.

Под идеей "делай что хочешь, только укажи автора" с некоторыми вариациями требований о работе с изменённым кодом работает большинство пермиссивных лицензий: MIT, BSD, Apache, MPL, zlib и другие. Осторожно надо быть с *GPL (вирусные лицензии, заражающие весь код) и MS-* (лицензии с ограничениями на использование). Исключения из предыдущих исключений: LGPL (заражает только одну библиотеку) и MS-PL (ограничивает только использование с *GPL) — всё это обычно не вызывает проблем.

Единственные лицензии, которые хоть как-то касаются денег — это CC-BY-NC из семейства Creative Commons и большинство коммерческих лицензий.